# Error for tune with package e1071

Tags: r, svm

I'm trying to `tune` the SVM model for regression in R using package `e1071` with the method used in [this tutorial](http://www.svm-tutorial.com/2014/10/support-vector-regression-r/#comment-259). Here is the data

```
> head(gps_rg5,16)
   Weather sex age occupation income weekday weekend age group          rg
1        6   2  57          3      1       7       1         3 0.035725277
2        6   2  32          1      5       6       1         2 1.693898548
3        1   2  63          3      1       4       0         4 0.009012839
4        6   2  65          3      2       6       1         4 0.014902879
5        6   2  57          3      2       7       1         3 0.045594146
6        6   2  76          3      1       4       0         5 0.003531616
7        6   1  65          3      2       4       0         4 0.001575542
8        4   2  57          3      3       6       1         3 0.009384690
9        4   2  52          3      2       6       1         3 0.033322905
10       4   2  56          3      2       6       1         3 0.011879944
11       4   2  56          3      2       7       1         3 0.008266786
12       4   1  63          3      2       6       1         4 3.055594036
13       1   2  42          1      2       1       0         2 0.029010174
14       4   2  42          1      2       6       1         2 0.000933115
15       1   2  66          3      2       5       0         4 2.342416927
16       6   1  79          3      2       4       0         5 2.891190912
```

And this is the code for tuning:

```
svr1<-tune(svm,rg~.,data=train,ranges=list(cost=2^(2:9),epsilon=seq(0.01,10,0.1)))
```

And the code returns an error saying

```
Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) : 
  Model is empty!
```

This is the structure of the training dataset:
[image: training dataset]

Any answers would be appreciated!!!
Many thanks!!

Comment: Please supply a _minimal reproducible_ example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I just update my question. Can you help me?  Thanks you Eric.

Comment: The error message say you are missing a model specification. Took a quick look at the tutorial and it specifies the model as `Y ~ X`, are you sure you can specify it as `rg~`? Could it be that it should be `rg~.` instead? Also, a _reproducible example_ mean something we can run in R locally to help you troubleshoot your issue. I cannot run your code as you are not proving data. Please look again at the link I provided above.